# Wf 4 Receive Activity: Difference between Messages and Parameters

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation

Receive activities in WF4 can take two kind of values, Message or Parameters. Does anybody know the different between these two?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much out there on the differences, but I did find one link that might illuminate the difference. Based on what I've found, it looks like the real difference is in how each is used by WCF. Check out: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/6fada456-435e-49d6-aaf3-283315b21c13

Based on how I read this, I *think* the Message is used when you have a MessageContract to pass in, whereas Parameters are for types without a MessageContract wrapper, or for DataContracts.